# Autoconnection to server with minecraft arguments

Tags: minecraft

I am working on simple minecraft launcher using c#. I would like to auto connect the user to our server using IP address and Port when user start minecraft.

To start minecraft I use process with specific arguments :

```
minecraftGame.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java");
minecraftGame.StartInfo.Arguments = CreateCommand();
```

CreateCommand() function create every arguments needed to start correctly the game :

```
arguments.Append("--username ");
arguments.Append(CommonData.launcherProfileJson.authenticationDatabase.selectedProfile.name + " ");
arguments.Append("--version ");
arguments.Append(ManifestManager.minecraftVersionJson.Id + " ");
arguments.Append("--gameDir ");
arguments.Append(CommonData.aramisFolder + " ");
arguments.Append("--assetsDir ");
arguments.Append(CommonData.aramisFolder + "assets/ ");
arguments.Append("--assetIndex ");
arguments.Append(ManifestManager.minecraftVersionJson.Assets + " ");
arguments.Append("--uuid ");
arguments.Append(CommonData.launcherProfileJson.authenticationDatabase.selectedProfile.id + " ");
arguments.Append("--accessToken ");
arguments.Append(CommonData.launcherProfileJson.authenticationDatabase.accessToken + " ");
arguments.Append("--userType ");
arguments.Append("mojang ");
arguments.Append("--versionType ");
arguments.Append("Vanilla ");
```

Do someone know the commands to autoconnect minecraft to a server ?

I tried this :

```
arguments.Append("--versionType ");
arguments.Append("Vanilla ");
arguments.Append("mc.hypixel.net:25565 ");
```

But commands is ignored.

Then following this [page](https://minecraft-fr.gamepedia.com/Launcher) :
I tried to move the line **arguments.Append("mc.hypixel.net:25565 ");** to the third position (and some others position). But it still doesn't work and command is ignored. Someone got an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You can use specific arguments --server  and --port

Bye

Comment: ****Mic drop****